# Azure ldap authenticating users

Tags: azure, ldap

Is it possible for authenticating users while Application is in cloud and AD is in company itself. Pls let me know what is the process.

I see Azure having some AD facility[Azure Active Directory three editions: Free, Basic and Premium] but not planned to use this.

Comment: Is your AD accessible from the internet?

Comment: Higher Mgnt are saying something on using ADFS

Comment: Then yes, you could point your app right at ADFS and bypass Azure AD.  (Note that I said "could" and not "should")

Comment: Do you know what is to be done. I mean how to talk to ADFS etc.